# How can I loop through this json object?

Tags: python, json

An api return gives me this JSON:

```
'status': 200, 'result': [{'code': 'osgb4000000074565050', 'name_1': 'Durrington', 'name_1_lang': None, 'name_2': None, 'name_2_lang': None, 'local_type': 'Village', 'outcode': 'SP4', 'county_unitary': 'Wiltshire', 'county_unitary_type': 'UnitaryAuthority', 'district_borough': None, 'district_borough_type': None, 'region': 'South West', 'country': 'England', 'longitude': -1.77784130353605, 'latitude': 51.1989322399005, 'eastings': 415619, 'northings': 144436, 'min_eastings': 415126, 'min_northings': 143719, 'max_eastings': 416555, 'max_northings': 145363}, {'code': 'osgb4000000074573451', 'name_1': 'West Durrington', 'name_1_lang': None, 'name_2': None, 'name_2_lang': None, 'local_type': 'Suburban Area', 'outcode': 'BN13', 'county_unitary': 'West Sussex', 'county_unitary_type': 'County', 'district_borough': 'Worthing', 'district_borough_type': 'District', 'region': 'South East', 'country': 'England', 'longitude': -0.421810304962843, 'latitude': 50.8324879562536, 'eastings': 511236, 'northings': 104848, 'min_eastings': 510546, 'min_northings': 103835, 'max_eastings': 511721, 'max_northings': 105831}]}
```

I want to extract the "outcode". I have tried the following:

```py
print(data.result.outcode)` and `print(data.result['outcode'])
```

and this:

```py
for row in data:
   print(result.outcode)
```

and:

```py
for row in data:
    print(['result'][0]['outcode'])
```

I have pretty much tried every variation that I can think of...

Comment: Did you try `data['result'][0]['outcode']` ?

Comment: sorry guys. I got it: print(data['result'][0]['outcode'])

Comment: we got there at the same time. Thank you and sorry to waste your time

Comment: except you got there more quickly!

Comment: data = json_object